# How to maintain minimum distance between two trellis posts that are warping?

Tags: post, support

The posts on one side of my raspberry trellis are warping in towards the center which is causing the trellis wire to be less taut than I would like. When I built the trellis the posts were straight and level, but it fear that the posts were a bit wet when I buried them and that has contributed to the warping.

The posts are in the ballpark of 11 feet apart, and are made with 4x4 pressure treated wood.

At the end of the day, I am OK with the warping but would like to keep the wire taut.

My plan was to place some sort of stiff but thin rod between the two posts near the top, and this would at least prevent the posts from coming any closer to each other. One suggestion I have received was metal conduit , but other ideas I had were some sort of wooden dowel or PVC.

- Is the idea of using a rod-like object between the posts a sane way to maintain a minimum distance between the posts?

  - If so, what might be the most optimal material considering weight and exposure to the elements?
  - If not, what might be a better idea?
- Bonus: Is there a way to straighten the posts again (e.g. remove the warp)? Using some sort of cinch is not a viable long term solution as it would be a trip hazard in my lawn, but it would be temporarily OK as part of a fix. If it’s not possible it’s not a huge problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If this belongs on the landscaping stack I am fine with moving it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a ground anchor and a guy wire (outside the posts) - that appears to be impractical here since you're backed up against a fence, unless the other side of the fence is also yours.

Or: an angled wooden brace into the ground (inside the posts) at each end.

Conduit or other "thin rod" between them in compression is likely to buckle (bend sideways, down or up in the middle.)

Those *might* be close enough to use lumber between them, but that's moderately unusual.

*If* they have actually warped rather than been pulled in by wire tension, you could dig them up and spin them around so they bend out. And/or not crank the wires so tight, unless also bracing or guying them.

Comment: Thanks, braces seem like a reasonable suggestion.   RE: the tension - I believe the issue is not so much that I have been cranking them tight, but the weight of the raspberries is doing it for me.

Comment: @SethMMorton you've been around SE long enough to know that a "thanks" comment ain't the way to do it.

Comment: @FreeMan Not sure what you are getting at. I did not accept because I did not actually implement this suggestion and was hoping for some other suggestions.

Comment: You said "thanks" in a comment, that's usually done by an up vote instead. That lead me to believe you had implemented this as your solution. My apologies...